# Can I change the ETA parameter for a given celery task?

Tags: python, celery

I have a set o celery tasks that I run using:

```
my_task.apply_async(args, eta=some_eta)
```

But sometimes due to certain conditions I need to change the ETA of those tasks.

I can get the id of the task using `inspect` and `scheduled` methods and I'm wondering if there's a way to change the ETA parameter knowing the id of the task or I should revoke this task and start another one?

Answer (score 3):

`inspect` and `scheduled` are about the worker's (workers') queue and the queue cannnot be changed.

You can only change eta value before running apply_async() or delay()

Maybe you can revoke the task and start a new one with different eta.